# Remove values from array chunk only when all values are empty

Tags: php, arrays

I am taking the following array and chunking it into smaller arrays of 3 items using `array_chunk`;

```
$array = array('1', '1', '1', '', '', '', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4');
```

The following function and for each statement...

```
function preserve($value){
    if ($value != '') {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

$chunk = array_chunk($array, 3, true);

foreach ($chunk as $value){
    $chunk = array_filter($value, 'preserve');  

    if($chunk){
        $separated = implode("|", $chunk);
        echo $separated . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

...discards the empty values as seen in the array producing this result:

```
1|1|1
3|3|3
4|4|4
```

Next,

If the array looks like this:

```
$array = array('1', '1', '1', '', 'A', '', '3', '3', '3', '4', '4', '4');
```

The result then looks like this:

```
1|1|1
A
3|3|3
4|4|4
```

When I need the the results to look like:

```
1|1|1
 |A|
3|3|3
4|4|4
```

Is there anyway I can use `array_filter` to only remove the array chunk if all its values are empty and IF not preserve the values whilst still imploding those values which are empty as shown in the last output of results above?

Comment: i tried to add echo "<pre>" and return " " instead of FALSE, but then the |A| is displayed at the left side instead of center.

Comment: @SujitSingh I aligned the `|A|` for readability purposes in the example. The answer was to ultimately `implode()` the original value, not the filtered one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implode the original `$value`, not the filtered one:

```
$separated = implode("|", $value);
```

You only use `array_filter` to check out if the array has all 3 items empty

Answer (score 1):

You want to filter the outer array based on the filtered inner arrays, not the inner ones themselves. I.e. like that:

```
$chunks = array_filter($chunks, function($values) {
    return count(array_filter($values, 'preserve')) > 0;
});
```

*Edit*: also change your preserve function to do a typesafe comparison

```
return $value !== '';
```

because otherwise items like '0' will also get treated as empty. If that was your intention, you also could leave out `preserve` and use the default filter.